# How do Villagers react to Iron doors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, doors are a fairly integral part to a Villager's livelihood. They determine the population and the safety of the village. However, does an Iron Door have a different effect on the Villagers, namely because they can't interact with them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**They don't**. Iron doors don't count as valid doors in a village, since villagers can't interact with them. A house has to have a wooden door to be considered valid.